# Core Plot: should adding a CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation to plot space cause the entire graph to be redrawn?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am using Core Plot to display a time series of prices.  When the user touches the graph, I display a draggable vertical line at that point.  Both the time series and the draggable line are `CPTScatterPlot` objects within a `CPTXYGraph`.  This works pretty well - performance as you drag the line across the time series graph is acceptable.

The next stage is to display the price and date at the point that the user has selected.  The Yahoo Stocks App has a nice feature which displays the price in a label that moves as if it is attached to the top of the draggable line.  I have tried to replicate this using text displayed in a `CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation`.  This works, but it severely impacts performance.  After some digging, I found that `CPTLayer drawInContext:` is being called multiple times - it looks like the entire graph is being redrawn each time I redraw the text label (in fact my logs imply it's being redrawn twice).

Here is the code which draws the label (work in progress).  It is called by `plotSpace:shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:atPoint:`.

```
- (void)displayPriceAndDateForIndex:(NSUInteger)index atPoint:(CGPoint)pointInPlotArea
{
  NSNumber * theValue = [[self.graphDataSource.timeSeries objectAtIndex:index] observationValue];

  // if the annotations already exist, remove them
  if ( self.valueTextAnnotation ) {
    [self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:self.valueTextAnnotation];
    self.valueTextAnnotation = nil;
  }

  // Setup a style for the annotation
  CPTMutableTextStyle *annotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
  annotationTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
  annotationTextStyle.fontSize = 14.0f;
  annotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";

  // Add annotation
  // First make a string for the y value
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
  NSString *currentValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:theValue];

  NSNumber *x            = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[theDate timeIntervalSince1970]];
  NSNumber *y            = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.graphDataSource.maxValue];
  NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil];

  // Then add the value annotation to the plot area
  float valueLayerWidth = 50.0f;
  float valueLayerHeight = 20.0f;
  CPTTextLayer *valueLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,valueLayerWidth,valueLayerHeight)];

  valueLayer.text = currentValue;
  valueLayer.textStyle = annotationTextStyle;
  valueLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

  self.valueTextAnnotation  = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:self.graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];

  self.valueTextAnnotation.contentLayer = valueLayer;

  // modify the displacement if we are close to either edge
  float xDisplacement = 0.0;
  ...
  self.valueTextAnnotation.displacement = CGPointMake(xDisplacement, 8.0f);

  [self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:self.valueTextAnnotation];

  // now do the date field
  ...
}
```

Is the full redraw expected behaviour?  And is there a better way of managing the annotation without destroying it and recreating it each time the method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to destroy and create the annotation every time. Once it has been created, just update the `anchorPoint`. Removing and adding the annotation is probably related to the constant redraw.

Comment: Thanks @Eric - I was hoping you would be around!  I removed all the instantiation from this method but was still seeing the full redraw.  I tracked it down to the line where I update the value being displayed.  Diving into the Core Plot framework itself, I found that by commenting out the call `[self sizeToFit]` in method `setText:` in CPTTextLayer.m I could stop the redraw from happening.  Is there any programmatic way of preventing this call from being made?

Comment: No. `CPTTextLayer` is designed to size itself so that it is just a few pixels larger than the text. It has to update that size every time you change the text and/or the style. Because the size can change, it updates the graph layout. It shouldn't cause the whole graph to redraw.

Comment: I can't work out why everything is redrawing but it is - each time the size of the label changes, `renderAsVectorInContext:` gets triggered for each component of my graph.  I actually don't want the label size to change at all so I am going to subclass CPTTextLayer to make it fixed width - unless you know of a better way?

Comment: Hi @Eric.  I have managed to replicate this behaviour in CPTTestApp.  I inserted `NSLog(@"Redrawing: %@", [self class]);` into CPTLayer `drawInContext:` so that I could see what was being redrawn.  In the main demo window, find two points on the scatter plot whose values have a different width (say 1.74 and 1.6) and click on each of these in turn - you should see the entire graph getting redrawn each time.  I then changed `scatterPlot:plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:` in Controller.m so that the annotation and text layer were static, not recreated each time and got the same result.

Comment: If you're scrolling the graph, it has to redraw the plots and axes because everything moved. It redraws the labels because of the way clipping is done—if we don't redraw when a label crosses the edge of the plot area, you get all sorts of bad drawing artifacts. It could probably be smarter about when it redraws the labels, but that optimization hasn't been implemented yet.